# WordPress | Create custom meta title for single job page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using [Jobify](http://themeforest.net/item/jobify-wordpress-job-board-theme/5247604) theme for my wordpress site which comes with [WP Job Manager Plugin](https://wpjobmanager.com/)

So I'm trying to figure out a away how I could add my own custom Meta Title to the single job page. I tried reading [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_title/), but couldn't really achieve what I want.

I'm trying to get my Meta Title for single job page as:

Job posting title | Company Name

Right now it is- Job posting title | Website Name

Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Try with [wp_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/)

Comment: @dingo_d Yes, I'm trying to work it using the same function but not yet successful at it.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you haven't set in your `functions.php` file set:

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

Then in your header inside the `<head>` add

```
<?php
    if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_render_title_tag' ) ) :
        function yourtheme_render_title() {
            ?>
            <title><?php wp_title( ' ', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
            <?php
        }
        add_action( 'wp_head', 'yourtheme_render_title' );
    endif;
?>
```

Now you can easily change the `wp_title()` with what ever you want. You could put an `if()` condition in which you'll check if the page is your single page for job using [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) conditional.